# How is a header file using data structures without including any other file

Tags: c

I'm reading the source code of a well-known open-source software in order to understand an algorithm, in one of the files ([github link to the file](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_query_inline.h)) I read this:

```
ATTR_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT ATTR_NONNULL(1) BLI_INLINE
    bool BM_vert_in_edge(const BMEdge *e, const BMVert *v)
{
  return (ELEM(v, e->v1, e->v2));
}
```

The file does not `#include` any other file or library, I don't understand how this file is able to use `BMEdge`, which is a structure declared in another file. I also don't understand what `ATTR_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT` , `ATTR_NONNULL` and `BLI_INLINE` are, where they are defined or what they do.

Comment: Presumably, the file you reference can only ever be used if it is itself included by one of the other header files in the library - one in which the various macros and structure types have been defined.

Comment: @moamen Maybe it is supposed that this file must be included in other file.

Comment: I agree with both above, that makes it technically possible to do what you observe. However, if I catch a colleague at writing like this, they would have to change before the review is passed and the release allowed. We have a rule: If you use something then include what you need to legally use it.

Comment: @Yunnosch I agree 100%! There should be a `#ifdef ATTR_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT` (at the very least) at or near the top of that header file (and a corresponding `#endif` at the end, of course).

Comment: I find it hard now to follow the code, IDEs are not able to find declarations of those macros.

Comment: Did you tell your IDEs where to find the header files? They have and use a lot of magic but cannot do wonders.

Comment: a header file 'should' always be able to cleanly compile on its' own.  To do that, any needed data definitions are either in the file or the file with those definitions is included in the current header file.